# Fileupload Interceptor not uploading any file in Struts2 Maven

Tags: java, maven, struts2

I am developing an application in Struts2 in maven. I have used `fileupload interceptor` and `allowtypes as image/jpeg` but when I am trying to upload the jpeg file it gives `content type not allowed`. Do I need to add any jar dependency in my pom.xml?

Comment: Did you use "`allowtypes`" or "`allowedTypes`"?  (I.e., is it spelled and capitalized correctly?)

Comment: i have used allowedTypes , I am using maven. do i need to add any jar dependency

Comment: no, you do not need any other jar

Comment: could you post your `struts.xml`?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... try to use `image/jpeg,image/pjpeg` http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/mime-types.shtml.